# Confusion surrounding datetime import (Strings & Dates)

Tags: python, string, datetime, object, attributeerror

I'm really stuck on this part of my code and it would be amazing to get some input from somebody else. I didn't write this section and I am unable to contact the person who did (it is a group project). It does come up with errors when you don't format the input correctly (we are not required to do validations for this project so I would not worry about that), but what I am concerned about are these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mycomputer/PycharmProjects/project/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    stringsdates()
  File "/Users/mycomputer/PycharmProjects/project/main.py", line 29, in stringsdates
    birthmonth = birthday.month
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'month'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated <3 I really have no idea where to start in this section of code. Here is the code by the way:

```
import datetime

def yearadd(date):
    test = datetime.timedelta(days=365)
    return date + test

def stringsdates():
    # Inputs for first and last name, start date and birthday along with yearly salary.

    firstname = input("What is your first name? ")
    lastname = input("What is your last name? ")
    startdate = input("What is the date you started with the company? (YYYY MM DD) ")
    birthday = input("What is your birthday? (YYYY MM DD) ")
    yearlysal = input("What is your yearly salary? ")

    # ♡ Processing
    startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(startdate, "%Y %m %d")
    birthdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday, "%Y %m %d")
    yearhired = startdate.year
    birthmonth = birthday.month
    today = datetime.datetime.today()

    formatfullname = (firstname + lastname + ", " + firstname[0] + "." + lastname + ", " + lastname + ", " + firstname[
        0] + ".")
    employeenum = firstname.upper()[0] + lastname.upper()[0] + "-" + str(yearhired) + "-" + str(birthmonth)
    reviewdate = yearadd(yearhired)
    nextbday = today - birthdate

    # ♡ Output
    print(formatfullname)
    print(employeenum)
    print(reviewdate)
    print(nextbday)
    print(yearlysal)
```

Comment: you're accessing `birthday.month`, but perhaps you meant `birthdate.month`? `birthday` came from your input so it'll be a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read the birthmonth as `birthday.month` where birthday is a string which you are reading in from the user, and as the string type has no month attribute associated with it, you're getting the error. What you probably meant to use was the converted datetime object `birthdate`.

```py
birthmonth = birthdate.month
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! There are multiple new errors now, but the birthdate change was a good one :) 

  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/main.py", line 30, in stringsdates
    reviewdate = yearadd(yearhired)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/main.py", line 8, in yearadd
    return date + test
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'

I'm so sorry for my inexperience :( I have a feeling it is wanting an int somewhere but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it if that is the solution?

Comment: Glad to help. As for your new error it seems like you're trying to add `test` which is a `datetime.timedelta` object with an integer. I guess you can simply fix that by taking `test.days`. So just change it to `return date + test.days`. And please do accept the answer if you found it helpful.